# Maven jetty plugin ignores java trust store property

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project where I am trying to run the maven jetty plugin with a trust store configured as a system property using this configuration:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
            <configuration>
                <contextPath>/myapp</contextPath>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                <port>8080</port>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/myapp</contextPath>
                    <defaultsDescriptor>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
                </webApp>
                <systemProperties>
                  <systemProperty>
                        <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                        <value>localDev</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>javax.net.ssl.trustStore</name>
                        <value>src/etc/app-trust.keystore</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword</name>
                        <value>changeit</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>javax.net.debug</name>
                        <value>ssl</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I know and have tried this on other servers, but for some reason jetty seems to ignore the java trust store setting in the system properties. I have verified that the system properties are getting passed - (spring spring.profiles.active works as exepected). Any pointers on what could be wrong?